# Convert ZF2 Service Manager to ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a simple ZF2 application that uses two tables and a service and I'm trying to convert it to run on ZF3.  I can't work out how to update the service manager code.  Here's an example of one of the controllers

```
    <?php
namespace LibraryRest\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller;

use Library\Service\SpydusServiceInterface;
use Library\Service\SpydusService;
use Library\Model\BookTitle;
use Library\Model\BookTitleTable;
use Library\Model\Author;
use Library\Model\AuthorTable;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class SearchRestController extends AbstractRestfulController {

    protected $bookTitleTable;

    public function getBookTitleTable() {
        if (! $this->bookTitleTable) {
            $this->bookTitleTable = $this->getServiceLocator ()->get ( 'BookTitleTable' );
        }
        return $this->bookTitleTable;
    }

    protected $authorTable;

    public function getAuthorTable() {
        if (! $this->authorTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator ();
            $this->authorTable = $sm->get ( 'AuthorTable' );
        }
        return $this->authorTable;
    }

    protected $spydusService;

    public function __construct(SpydusServiceInterface $spydusService) {
        $this->spydusService = $spydusService;
    }

    public function getList($action, $first, $last) {
        if ($action == 'search') {
            return $this->searchAction ( $first, $last );
        }
    }

    public function searchAction() {
        $message = array ();
        $results = array ();
        $first = urldecode ( $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'first' ) );
        $last = urldecode ( $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'last' ) );
        if ($this->getAuthorTable ()->getAuthorId ( $first, $last ) === false) {
            $results [0] = array ('count' => 0, 'message' => 'This author not found in database', 'first' => $first, 'last' => $last, 'title' => '', 'titleCode' => '', 'link' => '', 'authorId' => '' );
        } else {
            $authorId = $this->getAuthorTable ()->getAuthorId ( $first, $last )->author_id;
            $books = $this->spydusService->searchBooks ( $first, $last );
            $count = count ( $books );
            foreach ( $books as $foundTitle ) {
                if ($foundTitle->getMessage () == 'Nothing found') {
                    $results [0] = array ('count' => 0, 'message' => 'Nothing found by library search', 'first' => $first, 'last' => $last, 'title' => '', 'titleCode' => '', 'link' => '', 'authorId' => '' );
                    break;
                }
                $searchBooks = $this->getBookTitleTable ()->getId ( $foundTitle->getTitle (), $authorId );
                if ($searchBooks->count () == 0) {
                    $addUrl = "http://newlib.rvw.dyndns.org/library/search/add/" . $authorId . '/' . $foundTitle->getTitle ();
                    $results [] = array ('count' => $count, 'message' => $foundTitle->getMessage (), 'title' => $foundTitle->getTitle (), 'titleCoded' => $foundTitle->getTitleCoded (), 'first' => $foundTitle->getAuthorFirst (), 'last' => $foundTitle->getAuthorLast (), 'link' => $foundTitle->getLink (), 'authorId' => $authorId, 'addUrl' => $addUrl );
                }
            }
        }
        if (count ( $results ) == 0) {
            $results [0] = array ('count' => 0, 'message' => 'Nothing found by library search', 'first' => $first, 'last' => $last, 'title' => '', 'titleCode' => '', 'link' => '', 'authorId' => '' );
        }
        return new JsonModel ( $results );
    }
}
```

What code should I use instead of the getServiceLocator() call as this is no longer supported in ZF3?  Elsewhere on Stack Overflow someone had replied to another question and suggested using a createService function but this has been dropped from ZF3 as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a factory to build your controller? In the factory (which has access to the service manager), you can load your `AuthorTable` and `BookTitleTable` as well as your `SpydusServiceInterface` and construct your controller with them.

Comment: In ZF3 controller classes are no longer ServiceLocator aware. that is why you should do as @Thelonias wrote in his comment; create a factory, create your services inside the factory and inject them in the constructor of your controller class.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different approaches, but you're already using the most common one: passing the dependencies in through the constructor. You're currently doing this for your `$spydusService` class, so change the constructor to also accept arguments for the two table clases, something like:

```
class SearchRestController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    protected $bookTitleTable;

    protected $authorTable;

    protected $spydusService;

    public function __construct(SpydusServiceInterface $spydusService, $bookTitleTable, $authorTable)
    {
        $this->spydusService = $spydusService;
        $this->bookTitleTable = $bookTitleTable;
        $this->authorTable = $authorTable;
    }

    [etc.]
}
```

then, somewhere you already have a factory for the `SearchRestController` (it might be a closure in your `Module.php` class, or a standalone factory class). You'll want to modify this to pass in the extra arguments:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'SearchRestController' => function ($sm) {
                $spydusService = $sm->get('SpydusService'); // this part you already have
                $bookTitleTable = $sm->get('BookTitleTable');
                $authorTable = $sm->get('AuthorTable');

                return new SearchRestController($spydusService, $bookTitleTable, $authorTable);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: got quick question .. is it a good idea, if we increase arguments numbers to use db models?, for an example if i have more than 10 models to use in a controller.?

Comment: @tradebel123 same question, solution is to add db adapter to controller arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to create a factory to build controller. This new class will implement `FactoryInterface`. In the __invoke function, you'll use the $container instance to retrieve all of your dependencies of your controller and either pass them as arguments in the constructor or set them on the constructor instance. Then just return your controller instance from that function.

Your controller will need to be updated with fields to support this. You will also need to be sure to register your factory in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and detail about the $container instance.  One point to watch for is the change of location of the FactoryInterface to
Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface

It's been a bit of a struggle but I've finally managed to create the factory for this controller.  Now on to the remaining controllers!

Comment: @user3017691 feel free to mark an answer as the solution if your problem is solved.